# How to get records from 91 & Above days - C# ?

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I want to get records of age more than 91 days.
I have a stored procedure (SQL SERVER 2008) which searches between fromDate and toDate.

I have to fetch records of
0-30 Days
31-60 Days
61-90 Days
91 & Above

How to pass the value of 91 and above from c#?

I pass like this

```
 fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-91) 

 toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(?)
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-91)?

Comment: I think he's asking about the upper value.

Comment: If you have the possibility to change the SP, an option is to check if fromdate is empty, in which case assign it the MIN(date) from your DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with the sproc, or if it doesn't date null values, you can try `todate = DateTime.MinValue` to catch all dates up to 91 days.

**Update**
For SQL dates you should use `SqlDateTime.MinValue` (thanks @Tim).

Comment: That's not a valid `datetime` in sql-server.

Comment: Is it a min  value or max value?

Comment: I understood the OP to be going backward in time, as in 90 days *ago*, based on the `AddDays` being negative and it sounding like an aging report. That would mean the dates would be decreasing, so you'd use min value.

Comment: @Josh: This might work, but in general it's not recommend to use a low/high value if you actually want to say _unlimited_. That might be inefficient or could have side effects if that value is used for other things(like an update). That's why `NULL` exists.

Comment: @Tim, agreed. If modifying the sproc isn't feasible this would be the only way, though, wouldn't it? If he can modify it, your solution would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify your stored-procedure so that it takes a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Then you could just pass the `fromDate` and omit the `toDate`.

You have to modify the query to take that into account, for example:

```
SELECT Columns
FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE (DateCol >= @fromDate AND @tODate IS NULL)
OR    (DateCol >= @fromDate AND @tODate IS NOT NULL AND DateCol <= @toDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

As your stored procedure requires a range of dates, the from being the lower bound and to being the upper bound.  You can try

```
fromDate = new DateTime(1,1,1900); // or if you want the absolute min (1,1,1753)
toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-91);
```